# Why hot key does not emit events?

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
  const next$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
    takeUntil(this.takeUntil$),
    tap((e) => console.log(e)),
    filter(
      (e: any) => !e.shiftKey && e.code === KeyCode.Backspace && e.ctrlKey
    )
  );
  next$.subscribe();
```

When user presses backspace with ctrl I dont get event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the key press sequence of Backspace followed by Ctrl, you can subscribe to both keyup and keydown event, so that you can keep track and updates the state of the `isCtrlDown` and `isBackspaceDown` variables accordingly

Refer stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ef3qgy?file=src/main.ts

```ts
isCtrlDown = false;
isBackspaceDown = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
  const keyDown$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown');
  const keyUp$ = fromEvent(document, 'keyup');
  merge(keyDown$, keyUp$)
    .pipe(
      filter(
        (v) =>
          (v as KeyboardEvent).key === 'Control' ||
          (v as KeyboardEvent).key === 'Backspace'
      ),
      tap((v) => {
        if ((v as KeyboardEvent).key === 'Control') {
          v.type === 'keydown'
            ? (this.isCtrlDown = true)
            : (this.isCtrlDown = false);
        } else {
          v.type === 'keydown'
            ? (this.isBackspaceDown = true)
            : (this.isBackspaceDown = false);
        }
      }),
      filter(() => this.isCtrlDown && this.isBackspaceDown)
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Ctrl + Backspace pressed');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.body`:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f82as7?file=src/main.ts)

https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-keydown

> Event.target : focused element processing the key event or if no element focused, then the body element if available, otherwise the root element